# Mac doesn't recognize USB

Tags: macos, mac, usb, external-hard-drive, operating-systems

Details about the Mac:

- MacBook Pro 13"
- Processor 2.5 GHZ
- Memory 8GB 1600 MHZ

Since I upgraded my Mac version to Mac OS X  10.10 (Yosemite), the Mac doesn’t recognize any USB devices. Neither disc on key, or my iPhone USB charger. The USB charger is not Apple original equipment but it all worked fine before.

How can I fix it?

Screen shot of disc utility:
[image]

Comment: Open disk utility and check if you can see USB there

Comment: I see 2 other things: Macintosh HD and descryptedFile.dmg

Comment: is your USB connected to Mac, If not connect USB device and post screen shot

Comment: yes. Just sent a screen shot

Comment: Check this link
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19094?locale=en_US

Comment: reboot and try again